# Use EF Core Power Tool to generate DB Context which inherits from IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am new to EF Core Power Tools. I have been using it for Reverse Engineering (Generating DBContext and Entities classes from Database). Now if I want to use Identity, which inherits the DbContext from IdentityDbContext. So, is there any way to create the DbContext Class which inherits from the IdentityDbContext ? Please help.

Thanks,
Regards.

Comment: Exclude all ASP.Net identity tables and add a partial class that specifies the inheritance

Comment: @usama-tabbassum I am facing the same situation. Did you find a solution?